# How to know it's the second login of user?

Tags: c#-4.0

How can we check that user had logged in before and its second log in?? The user checkin his time in morning and in evening they checkout time. how can we do it?

Comment: Severe lack of details in this question, if it even is a question. Storing the last user login time should be fairly obvious, and without any more details I doubt anyone will be able to suggest anything else.

Comment: Maintain your each user checkin and checkout time in Other table.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to persist the information of whether the user has logged in before. 
More concretely, you can count the number of logins and write them to a file or a database.

Comment: yup its solved, first of all checkin time of the user is stored in database and then if  checkouttime of same user is null then it will be updated in database.
Thanks, guys.